# Ubuntu command not running continuously with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying the below code to run command continuously and make pcaps of 5 seconds with different names but it is running for just one time generate just one pcap and then stops giving exception

```
from subprocess import run
       
command = 'tcpdump -i eno1 -w abc_{}.pcap'

file_counter = 0
while True:
    output = run(command.format(str(file_counter)), capture_output=True, shell=True, timeout=5).stdout.decode()
    file_counter += 1
print("Captured packet for 5 seconds")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "one.py", line 17, in <module>
    output = run(command.format(str(file_counter)), capture_output=True, shell=True,timeout=5).stdout.decode()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 491, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1024, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1867, in _communicate
    self._check_timeout(endtime, orig_timeout, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1068, in _check_timeout
    raise TimeoutExpired(
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'tcpdump -i eno1 -w abc_0.pcap' timed out after 5 seconds
```

Comment: May be in the second case, the command takes more than 5 seconds to execute?

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M this command captures packets so, I am specifying capture packets for 5 seconds then again then again ......

Answer (score 0):

Thrown error is because of the timeout parameter. Essentially you are telling the subprocess that the process SHOULD  finish BEFORE the timeout else raise error.

If you want to only let the process run for 5 minutes, you can close it after 5 minutes using

```
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Here you would need to keep track of the process PID and 5 minutes timer starting from launching the process. You can do that in your main using `time.time()`

Comment: I could not understand completely... could you please help me to set the code?